# using rewriterule to ignore existing directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a rather simple issue.  i have a URL on several websites that looks like this:

```
 http://marksdomain(dot)com/Foo/Bar/Mark.php?oldParm=value1
```

and note that Mark.php currently resides in a directory at:

```
 /public_html/Foo/Bar/Mark.php
```

now, **Mark.php?oldParm=value1** need to changed to **Lori.php?oldParm=value1** using the magic of mod_rewrite.  i am unable to determine to determine how Apache does this, considering the Foo & Bar directories exist.

i have tried the following:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^Foo/.*$  -  [PT]
 RewriteRule ^Foo$  -  [PT]
 RewriteRule ^Bar/.*$  -  [PT]
 RewriteRule ^Bar$  -  [PT]
 RewriteRule ^Foo/Bar$  -  [PT]
 RewriteRule  ^/Foo/Bar/Mark.php?oldParm=    http://marksdomain(dot)com/Foo/Bar/Lori.php?newParm= [P,QSA,L]
```

but it seems that i cannot seem to get Apache to move past the Foo & Bar directories.  I find examples for one directory level , but not two or more

what is the best way to accomplish this?

Ideally, i would end up with the following:

```
 http://marksdomain(dot)com/Foo/Bar/Mark.php?oldParm=value1
   --forwards to--
 http://marksdomain(dot)com/Foo/Bar/Lori.php?oldParm=value1
```

--and--

```
 http://marksdomain(dot)com/Foo/Bar/Mark.php?NEW-Parm=value1
```

will work without touching mod_rewrite.

thank you all very much.

"Despite the tons of examples and docs, mod_rewrite is voodoo. Damned cool voodoo, but still voodoo.” — Brian Moore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no mod_rewrite genius, but try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Foo/Bar/Mark.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^oldParam=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /Foo/Bar/Lori.php
```

Comment: "The difference between stupidity and genius is that genius has its limits" - Einstein

Comment: it also really helps to remove *ALL* of the .htaccess files hidden away in the subdirectories.